# Highlight text when clicked in tkinter

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, click, highlight

I'm working on my Python program (on an Ubuntu system), and I have little idea of what I am doing: I am importing media filenames from a folder, and print it in a `Text` widget, and then click it to open on `VLC Player`.
I just want to add an additional feature, that is: when I click on any filename, it should be highlight and then open on VLC.

Can you please guide me on how can I do it?

```
import subprocess,os
from Tkinter import *

def viewFile():
    tex.delete('1.0', END)
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith('.h264'):
            linkname="link-" + f
            tex.insert(END,f + "\n", linkname)
            tex.tag_configure(linkname, foreground="blue", underline=True)
            tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<1>", lambda event, filename =path+'/'+f: subprocess.call(['vlc',filename]))    # Video play on VLC Player

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    step= root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=1, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="ViewFile",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 6, column =3)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",            font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 6, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)                                      # TextBox For Displaying File Information
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=8, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=E)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    global process
    path = os.path.expanduser("~/python")                   # Define path To play, delete, or rename video

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a text widget rather than a listbox? A listbox has this behavior built-in.

Comment: I am not good in Python, somebody just advice me to use TextBOx that's y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your example to have the lines highlight. How to highlight a line is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422942/highlighting-a-clicked-line-in-an-unfocused-tkinter-text-widget). Basicly I added a `text_click_callback` that check which line is clicked and highlight it and calls vlc. I changed the input folder, to be able to execute the code, as I dont have any video files to work with.

```
import subprocess,os
from Tkinter import *


def text_click_callback(event):
    # an event to highlight a line when single click is done
    line_no = event.widget.index("@%s,%s linestart" % (event.x, event.y))
    #print(line_no)
    line_end = event.widget.index("%s lineend" % line_no)
    event.widget.tag_remove("highlight", 1.0, "end")
    event.widget.tag_add("highlight", line_no, line_end)
    event.widget.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")




def viewFile():
    tex.delete('1.0', END)

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        #if f.endswith('.h264'):
        linkname="link-" + f
        tex.insert(END,f + "\n", linkname)
        tex.tag_configure(linkname, foreground="blue", underline=True)
        tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<Button-1>", text_click_callback )    # highlight a line
        tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<Double-Button-1>", lambda event, filename =path+'/'+f: subprocess.call(['vlc',filename]) )    # Video play on VLC Player



if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    #step= root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=1, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="ViewFile",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 6, column =3)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",            font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 6, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)                                      # TextBox For Displaying File Information
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=8, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=E)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    global process
    path = os.path.expanduser("/tmp")                   # Define path To play, delete, or rename video

    root.mainloop()
```

How it works is shown below:

[image]

But I think Bryan Oakley is right. A listbox would be better for this. Nevertheless, if you want to keep using Text, you can do as in the example provided.

Comment: Thanks for your coorporation.....is that possible, single will highlight and double will open file on VLC Player

Comment: @FahadUddin Yes, you can do it. Just added `<Double-Button-1>` button. Please have a look at edited code.

Comment: Thanks for your too much help n guidance....Is that possible, highlighted filename can be save in a variable

Comment: Is there a Python function that will allow me to capture the text that is currently highlighted with the cursor and store it in a variable?